# does this code generate random numbers?

Tags: python-2.7, computer-science

```
a = 100
for b in range(10,a):
    c = b%10
    if c == 0:
        c += 3
    c = c*b
    print c
```

I was trying to make a random generator without using random function and I made this, does it generate random numbers?

Comment: Generation of random numbers is a complex issue. This code does *not* produce numbers that would pass a statistical test for randomness.

Comment: It's not random - in that if you ran it twice you would get the same sequence of numbers output, and its a sequence that is relatively easy to identify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer:

### No.

Your code will print

```
30 11 24 39 56 75 96 119 144 171 60 21 44 69 96 125 156 189 224 261 90 31 64 99 136 175 216 259 304 351 120 41 84 129 176 225 276 329 384 441 150 51 104 159 216 275 336 399 464 531 180 61 124 189 256 325 396 469 544 621 210 71 144 219 296 375 456 539 624 711 240 81 164 249 336 425 516 609 704 801 270 91 184 279 376 475 576 679 784 891
```

every time.

Computers and programs like these are deterministic. If you sat down with a pen and paper you could tell me exactly which of these number would occur, when they would occur.

Random number generation is difficult, what I would recommend is using **time** to (seem to) randomize the output.

```
import time
print int(time.time() % 10)
```

This will give you a "random" number between 0 and 9.

time.time() gives you the number of milliseconds since (I believe) epoch time. It's a floating point number so we have to cast to an int if we want a "whole" integer number.

> Caveat: This solution is not truly random, but will *act* in a much more "random" fashion.

Comment: I am totally convinced

Comment: there is one problem if I made it a while loop with 100 numbers it generates a sequence of only two numbers like 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1  1 1 1 1 1 1  1 alike only two numbers are generated and not in a random way

Comment: The idea is good, but you should just take the last digit directly rather than trying to do it via mod as it actually give seconds in the ones place, so you could just use: `print int(str(time.clock())[-1])` (time.clock is the intended function).